# issue with python list sorter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def my_list(num):
    rep=len(num)//2+1
    for i in range(rep):
        for j in range(len(num)):
            if num[j]>num[j+1]:
                temp=num[j]
                num[j]=num[j+1]
                num[j+1]=temp
    return my_list
x=my_list([1,10,5,7])
print(x)
```

#____________________________________________________________________________________

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\annal\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 10, in <module>
    x=my_list([1,10,5,7])
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\annal\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 5, in my_list
    if num[j]>num[j+1]:
              ~~~^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
This is my error . How can I fix this
```

I want to sort my list by the smallest number to biggest number using this method

Answer (score 0):

The valid (inclusive) index range for a non-empty list of length N is:

```
-N to N-1
```

If the length of your list (num) is N then you are trying to access *num[N]*

What you're trying to implement is called a Bubble sort. In its most naïve form, a Bubble sort is likely to be very inefficient. However, it can be improved by noting the index at which the last swap took place. Doing so can lead to a reduced number of iterations / comparisons.

For example:

```
def bubble(lst):
    e = len(lst)
    while e > 1:
        es = 0
        for i in range(1, e):
            if lst[i-1] > lst[i]:
                lst[i-1], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[i-1]
                es = i
        e = es
    return lst
```

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because you are ranging `j` from `1` to `len(num)`, so `j+1` is out of bounds. Also, you are returning the function itself, it should be `num`.
You can instead range from `1` to `len(num)-1` :

```py
def my_list(num):
    rep=len(num)//2+1
    for i in range(rep):
        for j in range(len(num)-1):
        # range to len(num)-1 instead
        # of len(num)
            if num[j]>num[j+1]:
                temp=num[j]
                num[j]=num[j+1]
                num[j+1]=temp
    return num # return num, and not my_list
x=my_list([1,10,5,7])
print(x)
```

Comment: When I run this, it prints `<function my_list at 0x14833a80e040>`. What am I doing wrong, and how did you make it work when you tested it? https://www.ideone.com/QtjOt9

Comment: Not to mention, also returning `my_list` which is the **function** not the **list** so it still wont print the list. The list is `num`

Comment: yes, I forgot to write it in the answer, but now the solution works fine